# react redux round number best practice

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I have a Redux structure
My React component calls sensorChanged() as this

```
this.props.sensorChanged(0.123456789);
```

I my action there is this function

```
export function sensorChanged(payload) {
  return {
    type: SENSOR_CHANGED, 
    payload
  };
}
```

and in my reducers there is this

```
export default function sensor(state = initialState, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case SENSOR_CHANGED:
      state = {...state, temperature: action.payload };
      return state;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

I need to rounde value like this: (0.123456789).toFixed(3)

> Temperature: 0.123

What's the best practice?

- round number in action
- round number in reducer
- round number in render function in react component

**EDIT**

Recommendations for best practices regarding action-creators, reducers, and selectors https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/1171

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In many articles, there is recommended that business logic belongs in action-creators. Reducers should be stupid and simple. In many individual cases it does not matter but in some cases it can save consistency of your code.

If you expect somewhere in your application rounded number and somewhere else original number, round that number in connect - mapStateToProps of your container instead of render method. If you round it in render method, your number will be rounded everythime when your component will be rerendered which is not what you want I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

In short, add it to your reducer if that reducer will always need to round off the number it receives. This way, you can call that reducer elsewhere and benefit from centralized business logic.

If you think that reducer might sometimes be used for 0.123 and other times 0.12345... then round in the render function

You might just be using this reducer from a single place ever. In that case, I'd still add this function to the reducer. It's pure.